# Mocking a Supplier<>-Bean

Tags: spring-boot, testing, mockito, spring-boot-test, cucumber-java

I would like to mock a Bean (using mockito) that is defined like so

```
@Bean("idGenerator")
public Supplier<UUID> idGenerator() {
  return () -> UUID.randomUUID();
}
```

In a `SpringBootTest`-class I get an error using `@MockBean` indicating, that that Bean cannot be mocked (due to some limitations in the JVM? - sorry, I don't have the stacktrace at hand right now).

I came up with a workaround that does not use Mocks but an additional field in a `@TestConfiguration` so that the return-value of the supplier can be specified externally.

Since I don't really like that workaround (and my colleagues won't either), I hope there is a proved pattern or the realization I am doing that mocking wrong.

## Edit

Here is the stacktrace I am getting. As Markus pointed out - the standard unit-tests work - it seems to be a shortcoming of cucumber-java:

```
Before All/After All failed
io.cucumber.core.exception.CompositeCucumberException: There were 15 exceptions. The details are in the stacktrace below.
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.getThrowable(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:57)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.getThrowable(CucumberExecutionContext.java:102)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.finishTestRun(CucumberExecutionContext.java:97)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.execute(Runtime.java:96)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.Runtime.run(Runtime.java:87)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:87)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.main(Main.java:30)
    Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
        at io.cucumber.spring.TestContextAdaptor.<init>(TestContextAdaptor.java:32)
        at io.cucumber.spring.SpringFactory.start(SpringFactory.java:120)
        at io.cucumber.core.runner.Runner.buildBackendWorlds(Runner.java:134)
[...]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name [...]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 5: Initialization of bean failed; 
    nested exception is org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot mock/spy class BackendApplicationConfiguration$$Lambda$1713/0x00000008018fd980
Mockito cannot mock/spy because :
 - VM does not support modification of given type
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just define it like follows:

```
@MockBean(name = "idGenerator")
private Supplier<UUID> mockedSupplier;
```

there is no issue that prevents this from mocking. Would be good to include your stacktrace, as the issue is probably somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks - it was an important information that it _should_ work. 
Seems to be a problem with cucumber-java.